# Is there a comprehensive list of licenses on the web?

Tags: licensing

Is there a comprehensive list of licenses freely available on the web? It should include both copyleft and copyright licenses.

A link to the webpage and description would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GNU webpage has an extensive list of licenses with a short description about each one. It breaks down the licenses by software, documentation, and miscellaneous licenses. Emphasis is placed on which licenses are GNU GPL compatible.

https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html